# Как сделать данный код асинхронным?

Tags: python, asyncio, threading

начинаю изучать python асинхронность и нужно перенести данный код в асинхронный вид, так как в потоках и процессах основной поток блокируется. пробовал создавать задачи и асинхронно их выполнять, но не помогло. помогите пожалуйста!!!

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    with open(checker_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as base_file:
                futures = {executor.submit(checking, line) for line in base_file}
                concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

Comment: «в потоках и процессах основной поток блокируется» — чё? Отдельно запущенные потоки не будут блокировать основной поток просто так, отдельные процессы — тем более не будут

Comment: @andreymal окно в tkinter зависает и редактировать его нельзя из дополнительных потоков. разве это не связано с тем что основной поток перестает работать? на форуме видел фикс этого через отдельную библотеку, но она чисто под асинхронность, а как потоки пофиксить - я не знаю

Comment: Редактировать нельзя, а отправить сообщение из дополнительного потока в основной вполне можно

Comment: Ну и если у вас tkinter, то асинхронность вам всё равно не поможет: если вы запустите её в основном потоке, то tkinter точно так же зависнет в ожидании завершения асинхронности, а если в отдельном, то вы точно так же не сможете «редактировать его»

Comment: так есть отдельная библиотека https://pypi.org/project/async-tkinter-loop/ для работы асинхронных функций и окна ткинтер в одно время.

Comment: У неё в коде `await asyncio.sleep(0.01)` - страшно

Comment: Убираете wait - основной поток прекращает блокироваться.

Comment: @andreymal почему страшно?)

Comment: @insolor это означает, что код зазря дёргает процессор сто раз в секунду и что частота кадров, вероятно, будет ограничена сотней (последнее, наверно, не очень важно для tkinter-приложений, но как пытающийся играть в osu! на мониторе 165 Гц я недоволен)

Comment: @andreymal хз как лучше. Если `await asyncio.sleep(0)`, то теоретически частота обновления не будет ограничена 100Гц, но и ядро будет грузить на 100%. 0.01 это - как бы компромисс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хочешь на `asyncio`, то можно использовать библиотеку [`aiofiles`](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles).

Тебе нужно сначала функцию checking тоже сделать асинхронной:

```
async def checking(line: str):
    ...
```

Не забыть импортировать:

```
import asyncio
import aiofiles
```

И основной код:

```
async def main():
    async with aiofiles.open(checker_file) as f:
        async for line in f:
            await checking(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

И еще рекомендую почитать статью про [генераторы и asyncio](https://go-coding.dev/article/Delaem-svoi-asyncio-na-osnove-Python-generatorov-Chtoby-poniat-kak-ustroeny-asyncio-i-korutiny) чтобы понять как работает асинхронный код.

Comment: но тут только одна проверка в момент времени.

Comment: @eri в вопросе не было требования распараллеливать выполнение. Главное сделать асинхронным, чтобы проверка не блокировала весь поток.